# Is there a difference between these 2 arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
float kernel[kernel_size][kernel_size] = {
        0.000036, 0.000363, 0.001446, 0.002291, 0.001446, 0.000363, 0.000036,
        0.000363, 0.003676, 0.014662, 0.023226, 0.014662, 0.003676, 0.000363,
        0.001446, 0.014662, 0.058488, 0.092651, 0.058488, 0.014662, 0.001446,
        0.002291, 0.023226, 0.092651, 0.146768, 0.092651, 0.023226, 0.002291,
        0.001446, 0.014662, 0.058488, 0.092651, 0.058488, 0.014662, 0.001446,
        0.000363, 0.003676, 0.014662, 0.023226, 0.014662, 0.003676, 0.000363,
        0.000036, 0.000363, 0.001446, 0.002291, 0.001446, 0.000363, 0.000036
};


float kernel[kernel_size][kernel_size] = {
            {0.000036, 0.000363, 0.001446, 0.002291, 0.001446, 0.000363, 0.000036},
            {0.000363, 0.003676, 0.014662, 0.023226, 0.014662, 0.003676, 0.000363},
            {0.001446, 0.014662, 0.058488, 0.092651, 0.058488, 0.014662, 0.001446},
            {0.002291, 0.023226, 0.092651, 0.146768, 0.092651, 0.023226, 0.002291},
            {0.001446, 0.014662, 0.058488, 0.092651, 0.058488, 0.014662, 0.001446},
            { 0.000363, 0.003676, 0.014662, 0.023226, 0.014662, 0.003676, 0.000363},
            {0.000036, 0.000363, 0.001446, 0.002291, 0.001446, 0.000363, 0.000036}
        };
```

As you can see, the second array has additional {} for every row.

Are these two equivalent or would the program behave differently if i substituted one of them with the other?

Comment: It is not possible to say without knowing `kernel_size`.

Comment: Depends. If `kernel_size == 7`, it's the same. Otherwise it's not.

Comment: Yes the kernel_size == 7, sorry I forgot to add that

Comment: @chris, oops. Yeah, I didn't quite look at the declaration. Deleting my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `kernel_size` is 7, there's no difference. Otherwise, they are different.

The first version will use the initializers sequentially to initialize full rows in row-by-row fashion (and zero-initialize the remainder of the array, if any)

The second version will skip to the next `float [kernel_size]` subarray (row) at each of the inner `{` (it will zero-initialize the remainder of each row, if any).

If `kernel_size` is greater then 7, this will obviously result in different initialization layout that in the second version.

Comment: You should explain why they are different. If `kernel_size` is greater than 7 then some elements are not initialized and their value is random. If less than 7 then you have an out of index error.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I'm pretty sure elements missing initializers are zero initialized.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki, If greater than 7, the remaining elements will be 0, not random. If less than 7, the program is ill-formed (won't compile).

Comment: Then the difference between the two approaches is not the value of some elements but the location of the values inside the matrix. This is why is important to explain why they are not the same.

Comment: yes kernel_size is 7 for both. Thanks for your answer

Comment: One thing I would recommend is to try it locally if you have an IDE that allows you to view locals when debugging. I ran a test on my machine than initialized the to 2d arrays you provided, which a different `kernel_size` each time. The view locals shows exactly how the arrays are packed based on `kernel_size`.

Answer (score 0):

First one is a 1 dia array with 49 entries and second one is 2 dia array with 7x7 entries